# facing issue with int to char conversion

Tags: c#

I am facing an issue probably with int to char conversion.

What i am doing?

```
> Create random password using Membership.createPassword()
> Create random digit.
> Convert password to array
> Get random array index and replace character with int
```

I have following code to generate random password with 1 digit at least.

```
GetRandomPassword(10, 1);

private string GetRandomPassword(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)
{
    int index = new Random().Next(1, 9);
    string password = Membership.GeneratePassword(length, numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters);
    char[] charArray = password.ToCharArray();
    charArray[index] = Convert.ToChar(index);
    string newPassword = new string(charArray);
    return newPassword;
}
```

However, the issue i am facing is with this line

```
charArray[index] = Convert.ToChar(index);
```

It does not store digit at given index but it stores ascii character like '\a'.
Why? 
please advise,

**How i can store number to char array at random index?**

Comment: Because it is what it has been built to do. And technically it stores a char with the unicode value of index, not the ascii value of index.

Comment: And I hope you know that you are generating a random number in the range `[1,8]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
charArray[index] = Convert.ToChar(index);
```

to:

```
charArray[index] = (char)('0' + index);
```

Now... What does it means this line? `char` in c# are more like `int` than like `string`... So you can do

```
int x = 'A' + 1;
```

and you'll get that `x == 66` (that is the unicode code for `'B'`)... The same you can do with digits, that in the unicode table are like `'0'` (code 48), `'1'` (code 49)...

```
int x = '0' + 2;
```

and you'll get 50. You can the cast back the 49 to a char and you'll get `'2'`.

Note that you are generating random numbers in the range `[1, 8]`. I hope it is what you really wanted.

Comment: sure i check. Appreciate if you can explain the reason as well. thanks

Comment: thanks you for explanation. What about charArray[index] = (char)( index); should be fine? Why there is need to add '0'? sorry i still missed this point.

Comment: if `index` is 1, `(char)1` is the unicode character that has code 1 (a control character), not the `'1'` character. If `index` is 48, then `(char)48` is `'0'`

Answer (score 2):

[Convert.ToChar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hkfdkcx(v=vs.110).aspx) will get letter by index, if you pass 64 you will get @. 
To get char from number you can simply `index.ToString()[0]`

Comment: why you used [0] in the end??

Comment: `ToString()` will return string and with `[0] ` I get character that can be assigned: `charArray[index] = index.ToString()[0];`